# Very specific error that only happens once in a while in python, blackjack game

Tags: python

I have a strange error in my code, I can play my game for around 30 games, but sometimes it outputs an error and I have no idea why. The game is a BlackJack game, I can get the cards to the player, and the computer and evaluate the value for each of their hands, but sometimes, after the player finish his turn, it outputs an error. Here's a sample of the error (it's kind of a big one).

```
  File "C:\Users\Carl\Documents\École\Informatique\Tp3\blackjackfinale.py", line 167, in new_game()
return table()
File "C:\Users\Carl\Documents\École\Informatique\Tp3\blackjackfinale.py", line 186, in table
print "Vous avez ces cartes %s avec une valeur total de %d." % (player1_hand,   total_player)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Sorry if it's in french but the important things are in English.
Here's the sample of my code:

```
def value(hand): #evaluates the hand of the player/computer
total_value = 0
aces = 0
for card in hand:
    rank = card[0]
    if rank in ('T','V','D','R'):
        total_value += 10
    elif rank in 'A':
        total_value += 11
        aces += 1
    else:
        total_value += int(rank)
if total_value > 21 and aces > 0: #changes the value of the ace if it busts or not
    while aces > 0 and total_value > 21:
        total_value -= 10
        aces -= 1
else:
    return total_value

def table(): 
global deck, mise1, mise2, montant1, montant2
player1_hand = []
player2_hand = []
computer_hand = []
if x == 1:
    player1_hand.append(deal_cards())
    player1_hand.append(deal_cards())
    pbust = False
    cbust = False
    while True:
        total_player = value(player1_hand)
        print "Vous avez ces cartes %s avec une valeur total de %d." % (player1_hand, total_player)
        if total_player > 21:
            print "Vous avez éclaté! Vous avez plus haut de 21."
            pbust = True
            break
        elif total_player == 21:
            print "\a BlackJack!"
            break #Everything up to this point works well
        else:
            cr = raw_input("Nouvelle [C]arte ou [R]este: ").lower()
            if 'c' in cr:
                player1_hand.append(deal_cards())
            elif 'r' in cr:
                break
            else:
                break
    while True:
        computer_hand.append(deal_cards())
        computer_hand.append(deal_cards())
        while True:
            total_computer = value(computer_hand)
            if total_computer < 18:
                computer_hand.append(deal_cards())
            else:
                break
        print "Le croupier à %s pour un total de %d." % (computer_hand, total_computer) 

#here's the error I get, it tells me that the value of total_computer is NoneType but I  don't understand why?
```

Hope I have everything set up for you to be able to understand my question and answer it, if not, tell me and I'll try my best to explain it. Sorry if I am not clear, as English isn't my main language as you can see in the code.

Oh, might be useful to show the deal_cards() function and the deck function

```
def create_deck(): #this creates the deck of cards
suit_string = 'cdtp'
rank_string = '23456789TVDRA'
deck = []
for suit in range(4):
    for rank in range(13):
        cards = rank_string[rank] + suit_string[suit]
        deck.append(cards)
        random.shuffle(deck)
return deck

def deal_cards(): #this deals the cards
return deck.pop(0)
```

Comment: You probably want to indent your code properly.

Answer (score 3):

In the `value` function, if this condition is met

```
if total_value > 21 and aces > 0:
```

you are not returning anything explicitly, so python implicitly returns `None` and that is tried to be printed as a number in

```
print "Vous avez ces cartes %s avec une valeur total de %d." % (player1_hand, total_player)
```

which is NOT possible. Thats why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Notice here:

```
def value(hand):
    ...
    if total_value > 21 and aces > 0: #changes the value of the ace if it busts or not
        while aces > 0 and total_value > 21:
            total_value -= 10
            aces -= 1 
    else: 
        return total_value
```

If you bust with an ace, then the value() doesn't return total_value. In python, if you reach the end of the function without returning anything, it returns None, thus you get None.

Comment: So I should add a return total_value after this part?

Comment: Thanks it works now! Didn't thought that would be an easy fix!